# Why Can't I use a model inside a controller?

Tags: php, laravel

This is the `ContactsController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    .
    .
    .  
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $contact = Contact::find($id);
        print_r(App\Group::find(1));
        return view('contacts.edit');
    }
    .
    .
    . 
}
```

The `Contact.php` and `Group.php` models are already created in `app` folder. The problem is I can use `App\Group::find(1)` inside a `.blade.php` file but I can't use it in a method of a controller. My code reports the following error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Group' not found

I also tried `print_r(Group::find(1));` the same error reported.

thanks

Comment: add your model to this controller . before the calss just write 
use App\Contact; if your model is in app folder other give path where is your model.

Comment: @KuldeepMishra I know this works, But why in a `.blade.php` file I don't need  to add `use App\Group`?

Comment: You should _not_ be accessing models in your views. Your controller should be passing your views the data they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `use App\Group;` to the top of the file to import the class.

Comment: I know this works, But why in a `.blade.php` file I don't need  to add `use App\Group`?

Comment: Because the `.blade` files are build in the global namespace. So when you reference literally `App\Group` in your view, it can find the model. However when you're in your controller and you reference the model it looks for it relative to the current namespace - literally `App\Http\Controllers\Group`. So you have two options - add `use` at the top to tell PHP to use another namespace, or use it with a prefixed slash like `\App\Group` which tells PHP to get it from the root namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Add below line after use App\Contact

use App\Group

Comment: I know this works, But why in a `.blade.php` file I don't need  to add `use App\Group`?

Answer (score 1):

You can import your model with `use Namespace\Model;` You can also use fully qualified namespaces so you don't have to import them on top of your file. You can use fully qualified namespaces by adding a backslash in front of your namespace. You can do that in your blade templates.

```
{{ \Namespace\Model::someStaticFunction() }}
```

You can do that or you can use Facades maybe you're mixing them.